# Howto do not re-run already executed transformers in FME?

Tags: fme-form

I have a FME workspace with several transformers. I have already run the workspace.

Now I change a transformer at the end of the workspace (marked in red here).

How can I ensure that only the new part (red) is executed when I execute it again? The part already executed (green) should not be executed again (to save time).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it with FME 2018 version making use of run with feature cache.

Enable feature cache and you will access to run from this , run to this and run just this. see pictures attached.

Be aware feature cache as name mentions will need to cache features in FME TEMP area , so your FME TEMP area may fill up and may crash some jobs if gets out of space.

[image: enable feature cache]

[image: enabeled feature cache tools at transformer]